# Using 'redir' command

Tags: android, emulation, redirect

Does anyone know how I can use `redir add tcp` command to try to get my emulator on port 5554 to communicate with my Apache Server on port 3128? I tried `redir add tcp:5554:3128`, but I got

**Error port already in use by another program**

I think its talking about the emulator on port 5554, but I think your supposed to run the command while the instance of the emulator is running. Basically my emulator does not connect to Apache, I think it might be the port mapping.

Any ideas?

Much Appreciated,
Graeme.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're barking up the wrong tree. :)

First, make sure Apache is bound to a public IP address, and not just localhost.

*(It doesn't have to be open to the whole internet, but it should be viewable by other machines on your network.)*

Then just refer to it like any other URL: http://your.machine.name:3128/whatever/

Comment: Hey, I changed the Apache httpd file so it now reads Listen myipaddress:3128, but it still didnt work. I only have one laptop at the mo, and right now Im using a wireless router for internet connection. I am using the below code in my app to connect to Apache, HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://myipaddress:3128/YES_BUTTON.php"); httpclient.execute(httpPost); Nothing happened!

Comment: shouldn't there be an `http://` in the string? I'm not sure. For "myipaddress", is it the *local network* IP address you get from your `ipconfig` command? (usually 192.168.xxx.xxx) ? Also, have you verified that you can see ANY IP address from the emulator? (Like in the virtual device's web browser?)

Comment: I can connect to the internet from my emulator alright, I'll try that "http://" in the Apache httpd file, I am using the IPaddress from the IPConfig, its a dynamic address, so it changes, but it is the 192.168.xxx.xxx address

Comment: So at the mo, my Apache httpd file has "Listen 192.168.1.1:80", and my App has "HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.1:80/YES_BUTTON.php");", and its is still not working, I checked the Apache access log and no connection was made to the server.

Comment: Beats me. Why don't you post the full source code to a small activity class that illustrates the problem? I'll try it out with my own home server on an emulator and see if it works for me.